# Get all XElement parents with a recursive function

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get all the parents of a given XElement. I tried to write this function but it does not work. the page loads endlessly.

```
public List<XElement> GetParents(XElement element)
{
    List<XElement> parentList = new List<XElement>();
    XElement cParent = element.Parent;
    while (cParent != null)
    {
        parentList.Add(cParent);
        GetParents(cParent);
    }
    return parentList;
}
```

Call :

```
Parents = GetParents(nodeOfPage);
```

Does anyone know how to fix my problem ?
Thank you

Comment: cParent is in the scope of your function, so it will never be null. The GetParents inside your while will create another instance of cParent, that the caller function does not see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the [`.Ancestors()` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353466).

Answer (score 2):

@SLaks suggestion is great and if I were you I will definitely use it, but it does not clarify why your code does not work.
Your code does not work because you have an endless while loop, you never change cParent inside your while loop so it will never exit from it. 

You can try this instead:

```
 public List<XElement> GetParents(XElement element)
 {
    List<XElement> parentList = new List<XElement>();
    XElement cParent = element.Parent;
    while (cParent != null)
    {
        parentList.Add(cParent);
        cParent = cParent.Parent;
    }
    return parentList;
 }
```

Or by using recursion:

```
public List<XElement> GetParents(XElement element)
 {
    XElement cParent = element.Parent;
    if (cParent == null)
    {
        return new List<XElement>();
    }
    var parents = GetParents(cParent);
    parents.Add(cParent);
    return parents;
 }
```